# convergence to infinity of$ (2^n + 3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ (as $n \to \infty$)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just checking.
$2^n$ ($n \to \infty$) tends to $\infty$.
+
$3^n$ also ($n \to \infty$) tends to $\infty$

so the sum gets me $\infty$.

Now $(\infty)^{1/\infty}$ : $(\infty)^0 = 1$

I see no other way.  Theorem: $n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Analogous:  $(2^n - 3^n)^\frac{1}{n}$ = $(\infty  - \infty)^0$ = 1 ???

Is it ok to suppose infinity on any integer $k^n$ as $n$ goes to infinity ?

Comment: Hint: this is $3\cdot(1+u^n)^{1/n}$, with $u=2/3\lt1$ hence $u^n\to0$.

Comment: Take some values of n say like n = 1 to 20, then evaluate $(2^n + 3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. What do you observe?

Comment: @Ignace I tried to edit as much as I could. (There was no latex at all in your post).

Comment: @Ignace, Didier pretty much gave you a "big hint" and you don't need anything more to solve this.

Comment: General advice: Do not substitute the symbol $\infty$ for $n$ or $x$ in an algebraic expression. In the majority of questions you will be asked, that procedure gives the wrong answer.

Comment: $\infty^0$ is called an "indeterminate form", and your example is the reason why: when you have a limit that seems at first glance to have this form, you cannot tell what it will do without looking more closely.

Answer (score 8):

Before I answer your question: In general you really should be careful with takink limits seperately. You have probably seen proofs that taking limit behaves well under certain operations if the limit *exists*, i.e. is finite. When your limits are infinte there might be strange effects. Just look at the series for $e$:
$$ (1+1/n)^n $$
For expressions like in your example the "sandwich lemma" is off big help.
Just observe
$$3=(3^n)^{\frac 1n}\leq (2^n+3^n)^{\frac 1n}\leq (2\cdot 3^n)^{\frac 1n}=2^{\frac 1n}\cdot 3\to3$$

For your "analogous" statement: You are aware that the expression in the brackets is negative for all $n\geq1$. Tking the $n^{th}$ root is not really well defined.

Comment: is not limit infinity?if we take logarithm of both side and use L'hopital rule?

Comment: @dato I am pretty sure that this solution is correct. If you are not convinced try to explain where my mistake should be. (Sorry if I sound patronising)

Comment: no you are right,i forgot  ln while calculation derivative

Comment: i got answer of this limit=3

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Another that keeps me troubled is n!/n^n. It simplifies to (n-1)!/n^(n-1). Of course the nominator keeps de/or increasing, asthe denominator stays infinite. I'd say the limit is infinite.

Comment: The limit is 0. Use the inequality $n!\leq (\frac{n+1}{2})^n$. To see that this inequality holds you only need $(n-x)(n+x)\leq n^2$.

Comment: I don't see the point. Is the first inequality a known one. And what do the x's in the second do to prove the first. And does it all prove the given problem n!/n^n.

Comment: So you ask me to solve it for you completely? Did you try working with my hints? I am saying 1. If you know the inequality it follows quite easily that your sequence converges to 0 and 2. The inequality is not hard to prove. Obviously there are many ways to do this. One possibility is to take two factors of $n!$ at a time and compare them to a certain square.

Comment: No, I would like to find out myself. But any books on the subject I have fail to clear out the basics for me. Any advise on a solid introduction to the subject, with good examples would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

We can use  following procedure: let $y= (2^n + 3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Then we can  see that
$\ln(y)=\frac{\ln(2^n+3^n)}{n}$
on the right side, limit is in the form  infinity/infinity, so use L'hopitals rule, take derivatives, we would have
     $$\frac{2^n\ln(2)+3^n\ln(3)}{2^n+3^n}$$
it's limits  is $ln(3)$, so finally we would have  $y$ is equal to $e$ in power of $\ln(3)$, so finally $y=e^{ln(3)}=3$.

I think is it correct,if wrong tell me and i will change it

Comment: How did you compute the derivative of $ln(2^x+3^x)$ ?

Comment: sorry ,i forgot ln,i will fix it

Comment: i have changed it,is not it correct now?